# Why can't I move a partial box definition into a local binding?

Tags: refactoring, agda, let, referential-transparency, cubical-type-theory

As a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279700/477476), I realized I need to use a heterogeneous composition to make a lid for a partial box. Here I have removed all the unnecessary cruft:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}

module _ where

open import Cubical.Core.Everything
open import Cubical.Foundations.Everything

postulate
  A : Type

  P : A → Type
  PIsProp : ∀ x → isProp (P x)

  prove : ∀ x → P x

  x y : A
  q : x ≡ y

a = prove x
b = prove y

prf : PathP (λ i → P (q i)) a b
prf = p
  where
    b′ : P y
    b′ = subst P q a

    r : PathP _ a b′
    r = transport-filler (λ i → P (q i)) a

    --        a            b
    --        ^            ^
    --        |            |
    --   refl |            | PIsProp y _ _
    --        |            |
    ---       a ---------> b′
    --               r

    p-faces : (i j : I) → Partial (i ∨ ~ i) (P (q i))
    p-faces i j (i = i0) = a
    p-faces i j (i = i1) = PIsProp y b′ b j

    p : PathP (λ i → P (q i)) a b
    p i = comp (λ j → P (q i)) ? (r i)
```

So here the only remaining hole is in the defintion of `p`. I'd like to fill it with `p-faces i`, of course, because that is the reason I defined it. However, this leads to a universe level error:

```
    p : PathP (λ i → P (q i)) a b
    p i = comp (λ j → P (q i)) (p-faces i) (r i)
```

> ```
> Agda.Primitive.SSet ℓ-zero != Agda.Primitive.SSetω
> ```
>
> when checking that the expression `p-faces i` has type
>
> ```
> (i₁ : I) → Partial (i ∨ ~ i) (P (q i))
> ```

However, if I inline the definition of `p-faces` into `p`, it typechecks; note that this also includes typechecking the definition of `p-faces` (I don't need to remove it), it is only the *usage* of `p-faces` that causes this type error:

```
    p : PathP (λ i → P (q i)) a b
    p i = comp (λ j → P (q i)) (λ { j (i = i0) → a; j (i = i1) → PIsProp y b′ b j }) (r i)
```

What is the issue with using `p-faces` in the definition of `p`? To my untrained eyes, it looks like a normal definition never going above `Type₀`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using agda/master!

The following would have also worked

`p i = comp (λ j → P (q i)) (\ j -> p-faces i j) (r i)`

with the introduction of `--two-level` the types of `comp` and `transp` trigger a problem with sort assignment for universe polymorphism, so some eta expansion is needed here to let Agda check the lambda at the sort it wants.

Hopefully we'll find a better solution soon.